# How do I make a function that validates a password and return 1 if it fulfills all requirements and 0 if it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, boolean, passwords

I wanted to make a function in JS that validates a password. The password must have at least 8 and at most 32 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and a number. Also it should return 1 when it fulfills all requirements and 0 when it doesn't.
My program returns a boolean value, but even when it's true, it keeps returning 0. What should  I do?

```
var validatePassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([0-9a-zA-Z]{8,32})$/

console.log(validatePassword.test("Password10"))

if (validatePassword == true) {
    console.log("1")
}
  
else {
    console.log("0")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to save the result of your `test` method to variable, and you put it in if. That is why even if it was `true` it never went inside the if statement. Save it to variable first and then compare in if like this

```js
var validatePassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([0-9a-zA-Z]{8,32})$/

let result = validatePassword.test("Password10")
console.log(result)

if (result == true) {
    console.log("1")
} else {
    console.log("0")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([0-9a-zA-Z]{8,32})$/

function validate(password){
  return pattern.test(password) ? 1 : 0;
}

console.log(validate("Password10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are vaildating the existence of your compiled regex variable.

This works:

```js
var passRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([0-9a-zA-Z]{8,32})$/

function isPasswordValid(p) {
  return passRegex.test(p) ? 1 : 0;
}

console.log(isPasswordValid("Password10"));
console.log(isPasswordValid("Pass0"));
```